# How to avoid restart activity in my cordova app when device is put into a car cradle (managing runtme changes)

Tags: android, cordova, android-activity, android-configchanges

there are a lot of questions around this, however I was not able to solve.

My app shouldnt restart when the device is put into a specific car cradle. I just want to ignore it

I tried changing manifest

+

What do I need to code if I would like to handle the Configuration Change by myself?

How would my onConfigurationChanged method look like to just ignore the uiMode change and not restarting the app?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
Here's the fix:
Modify your AndroidManifest.xml to include uiMode in the **android:configChanges** element.
After that your app will handle uiMode-changes all by itself and doesn't restart anymore.

Greeting,
Chris